# /rtabmap/cloud_map is only a 2D map

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I ran the following demo for rtab-map ROS without changing anything:

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_robot_mapping.launch rviz:=true rtabmapviz:=false
$ rosbag play --clock demo_mapping.bag
```

In rviz, when I change the PointCloud2 from /voxel_cloud to /rtab_map/cloud_map, I get a point cloud of a [2D map with only red dots](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12wp4rWC8y7Qowatv2BSF1S3fxJL4ocYU/view?usp=sharing). Is /rtab_map/cloud_map not supposed to be a 3D point cloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373784//rtabmap/cloud_map-is-only-a-2d-map/) by [justastudent](https://answers.ros.org/users/71771/justastudent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When subscribing to a laser scan, by default it will generate a 2D map. Set [Grid/FromDepth](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/0119f3e1fa31c02b63c75bb4e15033d4830f78eb/launch/demo/demo_robot_mapping.launch#L53) to true to use RGB-D camera to generate the map instead.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2021-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [justastudent](https://answers.ros.org/users/71771/justastudent/) on 2021-03-11**:
I see - however, if I set Grid/FromDepth to true, the [occupancy grid](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XVedPzcr540rJpbM8LEwFO8xzHlHtteR/view?usp=sharing) then changes to be less accurate than if Grid/FromDepth is false. Is it possible to set Grid/FromDepth=true so that the cloud map is a 3D map, yet also generate an occupancy grid like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zy51weGd_QKOESvg3uylbfgCpoFbo45H/view?usp=sharing)?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2021-03-12**:
This is because the camera is seeing the ceiling, thus creating obstacles. If you want to get both, you have to reassemble the cloud with `map_assembler`:
`rosrun rtabmap_ros map_assembler mapData:=/rtabmap/mapData _regenerate_local_grids:=true --Grid/FromDepth true`

**Comment by [justastudent](https://answers.ros.org/users/71771/justastudent/) on 2021-03-12**:
I see, is it because generating the 2D occupancy grid projects the point cloud to the x-y plane, so parts of the ceiling become obstacles? Thank you so much for your help!

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2021-03-12**:
Yes, a workaround would be to filter the ceiling with `Grid/MaxObstacleHeight` = 1.5.

**Comment by [justastudent](https://answers.ros.org/users/71771/justastudent/) on 2021-03-12**:
Got it - thank you so much!